# (g)Vim - disable history/viminfo at runtime

Tags: vim

I have some commands that I'm using to compress a file on saving, and post save uncompress it (just the indentation at the beginning).  The one thing I'm having a hard time with is that I don't want the commands to be added to the history.  Neither the commands nor the cursor position, etc.

I thought what I would have to do is to turn off the `viminfo` on pre-write and then turn it back on on the post-write.  But I can't seem to figure it out.  Here is the function I'm working with:

```
function! s:CompressIndent()
    augroup CompressIndent
        autocmd!

        " Befor writing, change 4 spaces (and single tabs) into 2 spaces
        autocmd BufWritePre * set viminfo="NONE"              " Turn off 'history' before making the pre-write substitutions
        autocmd BufWritePre * %substitute/^\( \+\)\1/\1/e " Halve the number of spaces of indentation
        autocmd BufWritePre * set tabstop=2               " Make sure that tabs = 2 spaces before re-tabbing
        autocmd BufWritePre * retab                       " Turn tabs into two spaces

        " When opening a file (and after writing the file) turn 2 spaces into (and 4 tabs) into 4 spaces
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * set tabstop=4         " Make sure to display in 4 tabs
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * %substitute/^ \+/&&/e " Double the number of spaces of indentation on Reading and writing
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * set viminfo='20,\"200 " Turn back on history
    augroup END
endfunction
```

I've tried `set viminfo="NONE"` and `set viminfo=""`.  Neither seemed to have an effect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's where I am now with this, but I'm still not quite getting it to work (now the indentation is broken, but the histdel() doesn't quite work either.  After saving the file, the cursor moves to a completely new position and the undo history has been branched or something weird:

```
function! s:CompressIndent()
    augroup CompressIndent
        autocmd!

        " Befor writing, change 4 spaces (and single tabs) into 2 spaces
        autocmd BufWritePre * call s:SpaceSubstitution("2") " Halve the number of    spaces of indentation
        autocmd BufWritePre * set tabstop=2                 " Make sure that tabs = 2 spaces before re-tabbing
        autocmd BufWritePre * retab                         " Turn tabs into two spaces

        " When opening a file (and after writing the file) turn 2 spaces into (and 4 tabs) into 4 spaces
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * set tabstop=4    " Make sure to display in 4 tabs
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost * call s:SpaceSubstitution("4") " Double the number of spaces of indentation on Reading and writing
    augroup END
endfunction
command! -n=0 -bar CompressIndent :call s:CompressIndent()

function! s:SpaceSubstitution(toSpaces)
    if a:toSpaces == "2"
        %substitute/^\( \+\)\1/\1/e
    else
        %substitute/^ \+/&&/e
    endif

    call histdel('search', -1)
endfunction
```

Comment: You change 4 spaces to 2 before write and 2 spaces to 4 after write. May I ask what's the point of such a dance?

Comment: The point is to be able to edit in 4 spaces and to save in 2 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating `'viminfo'` is too big a club to wield here. Commands that are executed by `:autocmd` aren't added to the command history.

The only thing I see is that `:substitute` pollutes the search history and the current search pattern. You can avoid a lot by moving the command into a `:function`, and invoke that from the autocmd. See `:help function-search-undo`.

The only thing you then need to do at the end of the function is remove the search pattern from the history:

```
:call histdel('search', -1)
```

---

Edit: To keep the current cursor position, wrap your `:substitute` with the following:

```
let l:save_view = winsaveview()
    %substitute/...
call winrestview(l:save_view)
```

Comment: do you think the retab may also be affecting it?

Comment: Hey - I tried implementing this.  See my edit above.  Still not quite working.  Any thoughts?  (Thanks)

Comment: Works for me :-) The search history is not modified. To keep the cursor position, use `winsaveview()`; I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Oh - that will be great!  (Not in Linux atm, or I'd try it.)  But, THANK YOU!  The one other thing that was a bit funky was the undo.  Sometimes it would add an extra undo and sometimes it would branch the undo (so I'd have to use "g-" or "g+" to undo back).  Were you trying it out with my function or do you have one of your own?

Comment: I used your exact function. The `:%s` will create an undo point, but branching depends on what you (un-)did before. No way around that.

Comment: So there's no way to turn off undo temporarily?

Comment: No, not without losing all of the undo history. Think about the undo implementation; would be pretty hard if you had a gap in there.

Comment: well, not necessarily.  Depending on the implementation, it might have been just a matter of not adding the next item or next set of instructions to the undo in the first place...

Comment: But even so, it seems that the histdel() isn't working for me.  Any ideas on what the matter with that could be?  do I need a setting in my vimrc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23720/discussion-between-mr-a-and-ingo-karkat)

Comment: While we didn't quite get exactly what I wanted, you did the best job and got the closest, for which I am very grateful.  Your post has been upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has four functions for manipulating the history, `:h history-functions` gives you a list and short description. Of the four, the one that you need is:

```
histdel()
```

which you can read about in `:h histdel()`.

Comment: Hey - I tried implementing this.  See my edit above.  Still not quite working.  Any thoughts?  (Thanks)